# Ubuntu 18.10: visual artifacts (black bar) in dock if extend-height is disabled

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I am using the default Ubuntu dock with bottom placement and `org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock extend-height` set to false. With Ubuntu 18.10 this produces a noticeable visual glitch, note the black empty spaces at the edges of the dock:

[image: click to open a screenshot]

I am getting this both on an upgraded system and on a clean install inside a VM. This was working fine in Ubuntu 18.04. Also happens if the theme is set to something else than Yaru (the default theme in Ubuntu 18.10). Reboot does not help. Dock looks OK if extend-height is enabled.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I had the same issue, but on Ubuntu 18.04. This problem appeared when I updated from v63 to version 64. Goto  https://micheleg.github.io/dash-to-dock/releases.html and try an older release.

Comment: What theme is that?

Comment: Haven't been using Linux in a while, but if remember correctly, this is the icon theme https://github.com/PapirusDevelopmentTeam/papirus-icon-theme

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like a bug related to adaptive/dynamic opacity: https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/814

To work around this temporarily, you can set the opacity to fixed:

1. Open Terminal and run

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock transparency-mode 'FIXED'
   ```
2. Reboot or re-login.

Answer (score 3):

Incase if you dont want to Use "built-in theme" option from Dash-to-Dock Settings and want to get rid of the additional length colour on both sides of dock..

[image]

take the backup of the file

```
~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/stylesheet.css
```

and edit the file

```
~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/stylesheet.css
```

like below at line number 118

```
#dashtodockContainer.opaque { background-color: transparent;
}

#dashtodockContainer.transparent { background-color: transparent;
}
```

to show the difference I have used cyan and blue colors in above content.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All is fixed when i switch "Default" in "Customize opacity" in Appearance tab

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Another possible way is this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1085622/480481